# App or way to add reports to a documentset

Tags: document-set, task-list, reporting

Dear SharePoint experts.

Hi

For a school project we were asked to set up a sharepoint for a non profit organisation. We made it so that we use a documentset for the creation of cases they keep for each client.

For those cases the employee assigned to that case has to send in an evolutionreport every 6 months. Now they keep those dates in an excel file so they see when they have to send in those evolutionreports and to see when and wich employee is late with sending in his or her evolutionreport.
Is there anyway to implement something that can do this in Sharepoint (I was thinking about the task app but i'l need a seperate task app for each document set.

Is this possible to implement? if yes, how could it be done ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can create a content type  'Evolution Report' for the document set and then assign a task through workflow which is due after 6 months based on item created date.

Comment: So i'm trying now to make a workflow but I have a problem [Searchaction person](http://prntscr.com/a4fod9) what do I have to put in the 2 bottom textboxes. as you can see i'm selecting a document set in the first textbox and then I select that I want to select value that is my Employee